# I'm trying to make my player be able to punch the enemy and for something to happen but My Collisions aren't working properly

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I added a tag to the fist and it's supposed to print out hello when it overlaps the enemy but it doesn't work and when I remove the actor has tag and print what hit the enemy it says the fist hit it so idk what's going on. This is in blueprints btw

I checked I used the right tag and that the collision setting were right but nothing worked

Comment: Could you post your blueprint nodes that handle the overlap please ?

Comment: Collisions get complex fast.
Are they on the same layer or channel?
Are they blocking, overlapping, ignoring?
Are you performing a Trace by tag or do you have a collision shape attached to the fist?